# Keep terminal always open on a workspace

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, workspace, mate

I have installed Parrot OS, which is a Debian-based system designed for cybersecurity and hacking stuff. Running MATE, I have 5 different workspaces I can easily switch to to make my life easier.

One of those workspaces I've decided to set as the 'Terminal Workspace', where I'd like to have always a shell open ready to execute whatever I want. I have made a little thing so when I log on a new shell is opened and maximizes on the current workspace, but this terminal is just like any other terminal. I can close it, resize it, and do anything with is window.

What I want to have is a shell that is always open and that I won't be able to close nor resize. Almost like turning the entire workspace into a shell.

To open the terminal I have added a startup process to my profile that just runs the following command to open and resize the shell

```
mate-terminal --load-config=TERMINAL
```

TERMINAL is a file I have where I have specified the size of the window, created by maximizing a shell and running the following command:

```
mate-terminal --save-config=TERMINAL
```

This is what TERMINAL looks like:

```
> #Written by mate-terminal 1.24.0
> 
> [MATE Terminal Configuration]
> Version=1
> CompatVersion=1
> Windows=Window0;
> 
> [Window0]
> MenubarVisible=false
> Role=mate-terminal-window-13582--1360735105-1588092592
> Maximized=true
> ActiveTerminal=Terminal0x562414fa42f0
> Geometry=126x30+0+27
> Terminals=Terminal0x562414fa42f0;
> 
> [Terminal0x562414fa42f0]
> ProfileID=default
> WorkingDirectory=/home/kolterdyx
> Zoom=1
> Width=126
> Height=30
```

Is there any way I can 'lock' the window in place so I can't either close it or resize it?

I am relatively new to linux (I've been using it for a long time, but i have started doing this kind of stuff like 2 months ago), so I may need some newbie explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can't but that I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F#</kbd> where `#` is 1-6 for terminals and 7 is for going back to the gui.